# How to vertically center table view in a Table View in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, tableview

I have Table View in my Storyboard.  So let's so I know I'm going to have a total of 5 rows.  Those 5 rows to not take up the entire screen space vertically, so I would like the group of those 5 rows to be centered vertically on the screen, instead of starting from the top and having all the blank space on the button because there are only 5 rows.

How do I accomplish this (1) Using Storyboard or (2) using code?

Comment: With iOS7, grouped tab are automatically "centered". Do you need iOS6 support?

Comment: No, I am using IOS7.  My grouped cells are not centered in the middle of the screen by default.  The entire group starts from the top of the screen till the last label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use UIScrollViews contentOffset-property, since UITableView inherits from UIScrollView. Here is a link to the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset

Essentially you just set a Point to define the X- and Y-Offset. So if you want the TableViews content to be offset by 100pts from the top, you would set

```
myTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -100); //(edited in response to Lavvo's comment)
```

and thats it!

EDIT: Since its a property, there is a chance that you can set it in Interface Builder, but i cant check that right now. If so, its probably in the "Sizes"-Panel, i would guess.

Comment: OK, this worked after some tweaking.  for the Y bounds, I had to use a negative number cos it was moving my group cells up.  So I used CGPointMake(0, -100);

Answer (score 1):

If your table view has a static height, the easiest thing to do in a storyboard is to set the height constraint of the table view to however tall you want it. For example, if your cells are 44, 5*44 = 220.

Then add a constraint to your table view to have it centered vertically in its container.

This will make it compatable with any screen size as auto layout will automatically center it in the view container no matter what size it changes to.

Comment: Makes sense, but the problem here is when the height of the screen is less than the height of the table. If a constraint is added to center vertically, the tableview won't be completely shown. Is there something to do solve this, like maybe adding a top vertical spacing constraint?